# Not able to get the date value from the textbox using angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datepicker

I have a html textbox, I have added the class 'date-picker' in the textbox. I'm not able to get the date values from the text box, but I give string or normal text values instead of date which is picked from datepicker. It is working fine. Appreciate your assistance to get the value to me. The windows.load function is used in my datepicker plugin(for reference).

```
<input class="date-picker" ng-model="Cr_ParentId" id="txt_parentcrid" type="text" placeholder=":input" />

 (function ($) {
/* "YYYY-MM[-DD]" => Date */
function strToDate(str) {
    try {
        var array = str.split('-');
        var year = parseInt(array[0]);
        var month = parseInt(array[1]);
        var day = array.length > 2? parseInt(array[2]): 1 ;
        if (year > 0 && month >= 0) {
            return new Date(year, month - 1, day);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (err) {}; // just throw any illegal format
};

/* Date => "YYYY-MM-DD" */
function dateToStr(d) {
    /* fix month zero base */
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    var month = d.getMonth();
    return year + "-" + (month + 1) + "-" + d.getDate();
};

$.fn.calendar = function (options) {
    var _this = this;
    var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.calendar.defaults, options);
    var week = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
    var tHead = week.map(function (day) {
        return "<th>" + day + "</th>";
    }).join("");

    _this.init = function () {
        var tpl = '<table class="cal">' +
        '<caption>' +
        '   <span class="prev"><a href="javascript:void(0);">&larr;</a></span>' +
        '   <span class="next"><a href="javascript:void(0);">&rarr;</a></span>' +
        '   <span class="month"><span>' +
        "</caption>" +
        "<thead><tr>" +
        tHead +
        "</tr></thead>" +
        "<tbody>" +
        "</tbody>" + "</table>";
        var html = $(tpl);
        _this.append(html);
    };

    function daysInMonth(d) {
        var newDate = new Date(d);
        newDate.setMonth(newDate.getMonth() + 1);
        newDate.setDate(0);
        return newDate.getDate();
    }

    _this.update = function (date) {
        var mDate = new Date(date);
        mDate.setDate(1); /* start of the month */
        var day = mDate.getDay(); /* value 0~6: 0 -- Sunday, 6 -- Saturday */
        mDate.setDate(mDate.getDate() - day) /* now mDate is the start day of the table */

        function dateToTag(d) {
            var tag = $('<td><a href="javascript:void(0);"></a></td>');
            var a = tag.find('a');
            a.text(d.getDate());
            a.data('date', dateToStr(d));
            if (date.getMonth() != d.getMonth()) { // the bounday month
                tag.addClass('off');
            } else if (_this.data('date') == a.data('date')) { // the select day
                tag.addClass('active');
                _this.data('date', dateToStr(d));
            }
            return tag;
        };

        var tBody = _this.find('tbody');
        tBody.empty(); /* clear previous first */
        var cols = Math.ceil((day + daysInMonth(date))/7);
        for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
            var tr = $('<tr></tr>');
            for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++, mDate.setDate(mDate.getDate() + 1)) {
                tr.append(dateToTag(mDate));
            }
            tBody.append(tr);
        }

        /* set month head */
        var monthStr = dateToStr(date).replace(/-\d+$/, '');
        _this.find('.month').text(monthStr)
    };

    _this.getCurrentDate = function () {
        return _this.data('date');
    }

    _this.init();
    /* in date picker mode, and input date is empty,
     * should not update 'data-date' field (no selected).
     */
    var initDate = opts.date? opts.date: new Date();
    if (opts.date || !opts.picker) {
        _this.data('date', dateToStr(initDate));
    }
    _this.update(initDate);

    /* event binding */
    _this.delegate('tbody td', 'click', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        _this.find('.active').removeClass('active');
        $this.addClass('active');
        _this.data('date', $this.find('a').data('date'));
        /* if the 'off' tag become selected, switch to that month */
        if ($this.hasClass('off')) {
            _this.update(strToDate(_this.data('date')));
        }
        if (opts.picker) {  /* in picker mode, when date selected, panel hide */
            _this.hide();
        }
    });

    function updateTable(monthOffset) {
        var date = strToDate(_this.find('.month').text());
        date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + monthOffset);
        _this.update(date);
    };

    _this.find('.next').click(function () {
        updateTable(1);

    });

    _this.find('.prev').click(function () {
        updateTable(-1);
    });

    return this;
};

$.fn.calendar.defaults = {
    date: new Date(),
    picker: false,
};

$.fn.datePicker = function () {
    var _this = this;
    var picker = $('<div></div>')
        .addClass('picker-container')
        .hide()
        .calendar({'date': strToDate(_this.val()), 'picker': true});

    _this.after(picker);

    /* event binding */
    // click outside area, make calendar disappear
    $('body').click(function () {
        picker.hide();
    });

    // click input should make calendar appear
    _this.click(function () {
        picker.show();
        return false; // stop sending event to docment
    });

    // click on calender, update input
    picker.click(function () {
        _this.val(picker.getCurrentDate());
        return false;
    });

    return this;
};

$(window).load(function () {
    $('.jquery-calendar').each(function () {
        $(this).calendar();
    });
    $('.date-picker:text').each(function () {
        $(this).datePicker();
    });
});

}($));
```

Comment: Well, every single book, article or video I've seen says that you should not mix Angular with JQuery, except in the edge cases. You should let Angular handle all DOM manipulation. What is the correlation between the markup and the javascript? Can you provide more code, please?

Comment: @Rodementou i have added the plugin code also

Comment: Use https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ it has an angularjs datepicker, quit using Jquery stuff in Angular